# maven: dependency compilation error

Tags: java, maven

My pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.myorg.write</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>cloudera</id>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.2</version>
       <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.myorg.Write</mainClass>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
  </project>
```

I am referring [cdh site](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_8_1.html)

I compiled it using

```
mvn -e clean dependency:copy-dependencies package
```

I got the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project simple-client: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project org.myorg.write:simple-client:jar:0.1.0: Failur\
e to find org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0 in 
https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/ was cached in 
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of cloudera has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute 
goal on project simple-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project
org.myorg.write:simple-client:jar:0.1.0: Failure to find 
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0 in 
https://repository.cloudera.com /artifactory/cloudera-repos/ was cached in  
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of cloudera has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Dependency cannot be resolved. I checked [this site](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/)

I can see `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0` in the above site. But what `jar` is in between the above statement? Does it cause the error? How do i resolve this?

I am trying to talk to hadoop which is runnin in another machine through java.

Comment: just to be sure, there's not a typo between "2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0" and "2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0"

Comment: Oh Man :) Come on You got me :) Yes It's a typo in my pom.xml also. It is working fine. Will you please tell me what `jar:` is in that line? Thanks. Should i delete this quetsion?

Comment: you could see the jar at this adress https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0/. And you can watch the pom at the same adress to look at the dependencies.
I think you can delete it, but do what you want ;)

Comment: Vincent Thanks. I asked you `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0` what `:jar:` is in this? Is it `groupid:artifactId:version` ?

Comment: oh sorry, it's groupid:artifactId:package:version.
package could be pom, jar, war, ear. In this case, it's a jar.

Comment: vincent credit goes to you. But khmarbaise added an answer. So will you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your pom.
The dependency `"2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0"` should be replaced by `"2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0"`.
You could check this on the cloudera repository.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your version `<version>2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0</version>` uses a `l` letter instead of `1`. I've checked the cloudera repository which simply does not contain a version `2.0.0-mrl-cdh4.0.0` but it contains a version `2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0`.